# Visited vs non-visited link contrast on Stack Exchange network Hot network post list

Tags: discussion, design, hyperlinks, hot-questions

[image: screen shot]

I understand Stack Exchange is trying to give individual sites as much liberty as possible, but I honestly find inconsistent coloring of links in the list of popular posts very confusing across the network.

It's confusing in general, but the list, being the same across the network, is the most confusing of all.

I'm leaving it as a discussion question since I'm not sure what feature am I requesting.

Comment: I am honestly not seeing any differences in the coloring. Where are you seeing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is bugging me a lot. The coloring of visited links is good on some sites, indistinguishable on others, and wrong on even more. Wrong in terms of violating the "greyed out means visited" design language.

An example where it is good (meta.stackoverflow):

[image]

An example where it is bad (meta.stackexchange):

[image]

For me, the second example clearly communicates that I have visited four out of five links, not just the middle one.

Across the network, greyed out / brighter links should symbolize visited pages.